# .NET Core 3.1 BackgroundService - Consume RabbitMQ and insert using EntityFrameCore

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, entity-framework-core

I'm currently writing a background service which reads messages from a queue and inserts these values into a mssql database. I'm using entityframecore to insert the values into the context.

Now I'm having an issue with the context. I keep getting the error :

InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()

Now I know this is an issue with async, but still...

I fixed this by defining a new scope at the beginning. But I'm not sure if this is the way to go...
Here is my code currently:

```
consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
            {
                using (var scope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    var context = scope.Resolve<DatabaseContext>();
                    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());

                    var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RabbitMQMessageType>(content);

                    switch (message.Type)
                    {
                        case "config":
                            await HandleConfigMessage(message.Body, context);
                            break;
                        case "measurement":
                            await HandleMeasurementMessage(message.Body, context);
                            break;
                        case "log":
                            await HandleLogMessage(message.Body);
                            break;
                    }

                    _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                }
            };
```

You can see that I just pass the context to the other methods and .Add() entities. 
Is this the way to go?

Thanks for the help!

Kind regards

Comment: Do you register `DatabaseContext` as scoped? How do you use `DatabaseContext` in that methods? If `DatabaseContext` is registered as scoped - your code looks correct. Do you have two `not-materialized` `IQueryable`s on the same dbcontext?

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework does not support concurrent operation on a single `DbContext`. If you want to use multiple threads to communicate with your database then you have to create multiple DbContext instance. [See MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/async)
So, in short the DbContext is not thread-safe, that's why the suggested way to register your DbContext in your DI container is to use **Transient** lifecycle:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>  
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(Constants.YourConnectionString)),
  ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Comment: Where did you find concurrent operations on single DbContext? By default dbcontext is registered as scoped and it's resolved from the scope in code above.

Comment: We don't know whether the DbContext is registered as scoped or as singleton, because the above code only shows the usage side. I just wanted to highlight that correct lifecycle management can help.